# How to convert a string value into a list of seperate digits

Tags: string, python-3.x, counting

I would like to convert a string of integers say 77150 into a list which would allow me to count the occurrence of a particular digit in that input.Here's my code for the same:

```
result=1
new=0
value=input()

number=[]

number=[int(i) for i in value.split()]

no0=0
no1=0
no2=0
no3=0
no4=0
no5=0
no6=0
no7=0
no8=0
no9=0

for value in range(0,len(number)):
    if number[value]==0:
        no0=no0+1
    elif number[value]==1:
        no1=no1+1
    elif number[value]==2:
        no2=no2+1
    elif number[value]==3:
        n03=no3+1
    elif number[value]==4:
        no4=no4+1
    elif number[value]==5:
        no5=no5+1
    elif number[value]==6:
        no6=no6+1
    elif number[value]==7:
        no7=no7+1
    elif number[value]==8:
        no8=no8+1
    elif number[value]==9:
        no9=no9+1
    else:
        break
numlist=[]
numlist.append(no0)
numlist.append(no1)
numlist.append(no2)
numlist.append(no3)
numlist.append(no4)
numlist.append(no5)
numlist.append(no6)
numlist.append(no7)
numlist.append(no8)
numlist.append(no9)

for n in range(0,10):
    print(str(n) +" " +str(numlist[n]))
```

So the input is a string of integers such as 77150 and the output is:

0 1
1 1
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 1
6 0
7 2
8 0
9 0

Let me know how i can solve this problem.

Comment: Use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how the output results from the input,
but if you want to count the number of digits, then here
is how to do it. Let `x` be the string representing the number:

```
In [67]: x = '77150'
```

Then you can make it a list of digits this way:

```
In [69]: digits = [*map(int, list(x))]

In [70]: digits
Out[70]: [7, 7, 1, 5, 0]
```

Ok, now use `Counter` from `collections` module:

```
In [72]: import collections

In [73]: c = collections.Counter(digits)

In [74]: c
Out[74]: Counter({0: 1, 1: 1, 5: 1, 7: 2})
```

And now `c` is a dictionary-like construct that contains 
the digits as keys, and the number of occurrences as values.

Comment: Could you explain what the *map does and that part of the code does not work in python 3.2 in an online compiler.Could you tell me how do i get past this?

Comment: Well, back in 2.7 map would return a list. In python 3 it returns a generator-like object. To convert it to a list, simply pass the result to the list function - list(map(...)). On python 3.5 they extended the syntax for unpacking lists, and [*map(...)] does what the list function does.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> ctr = Counter('77150')
>>> [(i, ctr.get(str(i), 0)) for i in range(10)]
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 1), (6, 0), (7, 2), (8, 0), (9, 0)]
```

The last line above shows, for example, that `1` occurred once but `2` occurred zero times in the string.

The `ctr` object keeps track of how many times each character occurred in the string.  Thus, `ctr['7']` would return `2` because `7` occurs twice in `'77150'`.  We use the `.get` method of `ctr` so that we can assign the value of `0` to any character that never occurred in the string.

For a more user-friendly form of the output:

```
>>> print('\n'.join('%s: %s' % (i, ctr.get(str(i), 0)) for i in range(10)))
0: 1
1: 1
2: 0
3: 0
4: 0
5: 1
6: 0
7: 2
8: 0
9: 0
```